# PostgreSQL - manually pull one db from old install data folder?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I had an install of Postgres on my Windows machine with a database in it and ran into some password issues. Long and short, I renamed the Postgres folder to PostgreSQL-backup, then uninstalled Postgres and re-installed it, then re-created the database.

Fast forward to a month later and now I want to check something in the old version of the database.

Is there an easy way to extract a database from the `PostgreSQL/13/data/` folder and add it to the active install?

Comment: No. Where was the password issue?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I just couldn't remember it and couldn't figure out how to reset it, and had only done a little work on the database except create some tables so I figured I'd just start from scratch. Can I rename the active PostgreSQL folder to a backup name, then rename the old one `PostgreSQL` and will it launch from that folder? Or would that cause conflicts and ruin files in other folders like `<user>/AppData`?

Comment: The password was for the database correct? If so you will still have that issue. Before doing any of this backup the existing working database.  If I remember correctly the installer will, if run again, create another install.  If that is the case I would do the swap on that install. If you still have password issues you will need to modify `pg_hba.conf` to allow `trust` auth so you can log in and change the password.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thank you kindly sir.